# f(x) takes only rational values and f(1)=1. then find f(2)

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be real valued continuous function on $[0,3]$ suppose that $f(x)$ takes only rational values and $f(1)=1$. then find $f(2)$:

$1)\, 2$

$2)\, 4$

$3)\, 8$

$4)\,$ none of the above.

Comment: This question is bad...surely the constant function $f(x) = 1$ is a possibility, in which case $f(2) = 1$.

Comment: @fretty The question is just fine and has a unique provable answer.

Comment: ...but none of the options lists $f(2)=1$!

Comment: @fretty What's wrong with option $4$?

Comment: Oh so that means "none of the above". It wasn't clear.

Comment: as f(x) is continuous, I assume f(x)=Rat(x), where Rat(x) is the closest rational to x. So the answer is 1 (=2).

Comment: That function is not continuous.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry "Closest rational to $x$" ?

Comment: $|p/q-x|=e$ such that $e$ is minimal.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: What would be the closest rational to $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: You can get infinitely close ($e \lt \epsilon   \forall \epsilon \gt0$), so there isn't one.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry So... what is $f(\sqrt 2)$ then? Your "function" Rat$(x)$ is not even well defined, let alone continuous...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Try proving that $f$ is a constant by contradiction. Use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Use the intermediate value theorem - if $f$ is continuous and
$f$ were to receive two values $a\leq b$ then it would
take any value between $a$ and $b$.

But $f$ takes only rational values - for which $a\leq b$
$$
\{x:\, x\in[a,b]\}
$$

is contained in $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Now set $a=1$ since $f$ takes this value. What is $b$ in this case
?